# Pi Pico. use it as a middleman between mouse and computer, Possible?

Tags: pi-pico

connect a usbafemale to the gpio pins(not sure which pins exactly) and connect the pico to the computer. can it just send the data it receives from the mouse and send it out without modifying anything at all just the data as the computer would get without a pico in the middle?